# Choosing between ets or arima model

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I have a time series and two models to choose from: ETS and ARIMA. 
I have used the MAE to select a model. 
But when forecasting the time series and comparing the models, I don't know which model gives the best results. How do you know that?

Here are the results of both models:

[image: ETS]
[image: ARIMA]

The first one is forecast of ETS model and the second one ARIMA model.

Comment: How come the black lines are different? Are you not trying to forecast the same series with two methods? Oh, that might just be due to scale. It would be nice to see both graphs on the same scale.

Comment: It is on the same scale. It's just that ETS gives large forecasting values. While ARIMA stays nearby the given dataset values. But the MAE says that an ETS model is better than ARIMA. But when plotting both models, I don't think that ETS gives good results. But I'm not sure. Can you help?@Richard Hardy

Comment: If it were on the same scale, the black lines would coincide. Just look at the axis. You can manually restrict the axis when plotting by supplying argument `ylim=c(min,max)` where you could put `-10` in place of min and `40` in place of `max`. Regarding which forecasts are better, it is hardly possible to tell unless you have actual data for future realizations to compare the forecasts with. You could try running the models on 80% of your sample, forecasting and assessing forecast accuracy on the last 20% of the sample. Then you would see whether ETS or ARIMA did better.

Comment: Maybe I haven't been clear enough. I have done a in- and out sample to choose the best model. Here, choosing the lowest MAE it gives that the ETS model is the best model. But I still wanted to test both models to see what future values it gives. For a school project I need to choose one model. Which model looks better? The ETS model gives a long upward trend, while the ARIMA model follows the past pattern.. @Richard Hardy

Comment: How can you tell which is better if you haven't actually observed the future? Only future will tell which one was better.

Comment: But that's the idea of forecasting right? You don't know the future and want something that gives an idea of what might happen in the future. So I guess I should just use ETS model because that model did better when taking a training and test set? @Richard Hardy

Comment: Yes, choose the one that performed better at the test set. Or perhaps a combination of both. Forecast combinations often outperform individual forecasts.

Comment: Thank you sir. How can you use a combination of both forecasts in R? @Richard Hardy

Comment: Surely, you can. Take a simple average of the two, for example.

Comment: A simple average of decent models is a kind of "ensembling" or "stacking". You could also train a meta-model that selects the weights from the different models.

Here is a link for further reading, including code in R: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/02/introduction-to-ensembling-along-with-implementation-in-r/